# QT - connecting QPushButtons with QCheckBoxes

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to QT. I started creating a TODO app and I want to somehow connect my PushButtons that are placed in vector with CheckBoxes that are also placed in a different vector.

```
std::vector <QPushButton*> buttons;
std::vector <QCheckBox*> checks;
```

I thought that the best way to do that will be to make a for loop connecting every element of mentioned vectors

Something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<buttons.size(); ++i){
    connect(buttons[i], SIGNAL(???), checks[i], SLOT(???));
}
```

But idea is the only thing that I have. I tried putting different things into SIGNAL() and SLOT() but none of them worked. By "none of them worked" I mean the fact that when button is clicked nothing happens. Program is normally compiled without any error.

Comment: you have to first decide what signal and what slot need to be connected.

Comment: Could you please update your post - what are the lists of? Can you use more illustrative example i.e. real signal/slot you wish to connect? What was the warning in console about connecting?

Comment: Might the problem be the fact that these buttons and checkboxes are not present at the begging but they are being added on Add button?

Comment: @JamesSmith If you are adding buttons and checkbox afterwards, what is the content of `button` and `checks` at the beginning? Maybe you are just doing an empty loop... You can't add connection to non-existing widget.

Comment: @Holt Yeah I have already realized as I wrote under mehmetfa's proposed way of solution. That was a bit stupid of me

Comment: I get feeling your lists are empty when you try connect button/checkbox and later you create/add items to list but you forgot to connect them (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just `clicked(bool)` for `SIGNAL` and `toggle()` for `SLOT`?

Something like that:

```
connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), checkBox, SLOT(toggle()));
```

Comment: first, try with just one button and one checkbox. then you have to be sure that the vector contains correct pointers.

Comment: Like I wrote above I have realized that the problem might be the fact that these buttons and check are not present at the begging as they are being added when the "Add" button is pressed. Now it works correctly as I moved my "connect" things into different place. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Works for me - and you can store the widgets directly in a `std::list`: that avoids the need to mess with manual memory management. Let the libraries do it for you.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <list>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget win;
   QGridLayout layout{&win};
   std::list<QPushButton> buttons;
   std::list<QCheckBox> checkboxes;
   QPushButton addButton{"Add"};
   layout.addWidget(&addButton, 0, 0, 2, 1);
   auto const clicked = &QAbstractButton::clicked;
   auto const toggle = &QAbstractButton::toggle;
   auto const add = [&,clicked,toggle]{
      int const col = layout.columnCount();
      auto const text = QString::number(col);
      auto *button = &(buttons.emplace_back(text), buttons.back()); //C++11, not 14
      auto *checkbox = &(checkboxes.emplace_back(text), checkboxes.back());
      layout.addWidget(button, 0, col);
      layout.addWidget(checkbox, 1, col);
      QObject::connect(button, clicked, checkbox, toggle);
   };
   add();
   QObject::connect(&addButton, clicked, add);
   win.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Remember that you should choose to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) over std::list by default unless you know you actually require a linked list.

Comment: @PaulB Widgets are non-copyable and non-moveable :) This wasn't an uninformed selection.

Answer (score 0):

With Qt-5 you can now use lambda functions as slots (see [connect version 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5))

You can also do away with the need for the `SIGNAL` macro, and instead use member function pointers.

```
QObject::connect(buttons[i], &QPushButton::clicked, [=]
    {
        // toggle the check state
        checks[i]->setChecked(!checks[i]->isChecked());
    });
```

The first two parameters are a pointer to an object, and a member function pointer

- `buttons[i]` is of type `QPushButton*`
- `&QPushButton::clicked` is a member function pointer of the signal you want to connect to

The second parameter is a C++11 lambda, which captures `checked` and `i` by value, and then sets the `QCheckBox` checked state to the inverse of its previous value

Comment: You can replace your lambda by `checks[i], &QCheckBox::toggle`.